# 70s-80s(?) sci-fi book with a woman seeing the end and beginning of the universe, talks to her past self, clones herself

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I read this book in 6th grade (2002-2003 school year). It has a female character and she meets this guy a week before she has to leave on a space mission with her father. Somehow she sees the end and beginning of the universe. She goes back and talks to her past self. She also gets with the guy she met. She clones herself and the guy. It is like a time loop. And I believe she meets a blue alien child.

In the first chapter she coming back from the library were she was learning about the 20th century. She started to sing Led Zeppelin's rock and roll.

It had a classic sci-fi cover. The main character was on the cover wearing a purple space suit. The cover looked like it could be from the 70's or 80's and the cover wasn't sexualized at all. I believe it was a book directed to teenagers.

Comment: Yea that is the problem. It was a donated book at my middle school. I sat by the book shelf and I just use to pull books off everyday to read. I knew nothing about science fiction or the year it was released. Thanks for answering tho

Comment: @Timmeka You say you read it in sixth grade—when was that? 2008? 1955? At least we'll know then that it must be at the very least from before that year.

Comment: @Janus It was 2002-2003 school year.sl

Answer (score 7):

*The Starlight Crystal* (1995) by Christopher Pike.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137967.The_Starlight_Crystal#):

> It is 200 years in the future. Paige Christian, 18, has been given the chance to join the crew of the Traveler--a special spaceship/time capsule designed to circle the solar system and study the changes on earth throughout two centuries. But an awful thing happens to the earth--and the Traveler.

[image: book cover, character in a spacesuit looking at a two-seater tall hourglass]

Comment: That's it!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. I was trying to find a section to quote, but never mind :)

Comment: Its been years lol you are a rock star

Comment: Holy smokes! The authors name!